# ¿Optimizar actualización de datos en tabla Access mediante Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

Tengo una aplicación Excel conectada a una base de datos Access en la que inserto, consulto y actualizo datos. A la hora de actualizar datos me surge la duda de si existe un método más efectivo, ya que yo voy recorriendo fila a fila, formando mi recordset y luego actualizando los datos. Lo hago con el siguiente código  y conecto mediante ADO:

```
Do While fila <= lastrow

        ID = ws.Cells(fila, 1).Value

        strSQL = "SELECT * FROM datos WHERE ID = " & ID

        'Base de datos
        Nombrebd = "datosguias.accdb"
        'Ruta bbdd
        Rutabbdd = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Datos"
        strDB = Rutabbdd & "\" & Nombrebd
        AccessConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; data source= " & strDB & ";Jet OLEDB:Database password=iddqd0001"

        'Abro la conexión
        Conn1.Open (AccessConnect)

        'Creo el recordset
        Set adoRecSet = New ADODB.Recordset
        adoRecSet.CursorLocation = adUseServer

        'Abro la conexión
        adoRecSet.Open Source:=strSQL, ActiveConnection:=Conn1, CursorType:=adOpenKeyset, LockType:=adLockOptimistic

        'Si he añadido una entrega la marco como Grabada
        If ws.Cells(fila, 10).Value = "" Then
            estatus = "Pendiente"
        Else
            estatus = "Grabada"
        End If

        'Monto el recordset con los nuevos datos
        With adoRecSet
            .Fields(1) = Cells(fila, 2).Value       'Almacen
            .Fields(2) = Cells(fila, 3).Value       'Fecha
            .Fields(3) = Cells(fila, 4).Value       'CRM
            .Fields(4) = Cells(fila, 5).Value       'Cliente
            .Fields(5) = Cells(fila, 6).Value       'Codigo producto
            .Fields(6) = Cells(fila, 7).Value       'Descripción producto
            .Fields(7) = Cells(fila, 8).Value       'Cantidad
            .Fields(8) = Cells(fila, 9).Value       'Transito
            .Fields(9) = Cells(fila, 10).Value      'Entrega
            .Fields(10) = estatus                   'Situación CRM
            .Fields(11) = NombreUsuario             'Usuario que lo edita
            .Fields(12) = Now()                     'Momento de actualización

            'Actualizo el recordset
            adoRecSet.Update

        End With

        'Cierro recordset y conexion
        adoRecSet.Close
        Conn1.Close
        'Libero memoria
        Set adoRecSet = Nothing
        Set Conn1 = Nothing

        'Sumo una fila y paso al siguiente recordset
        fila = fila + 1

    Loop
```

Hay alguna forma de hacerlo todo sin necesidad de recorrer fila a fila, formar el recordset y actualizar uno a uno los registros?

Ahora mismo no manejo muchos datos en el Excel y la velocidad no se resiente pero en un futuro la cantidad de registros a insertar y modificar será bastante más elevada y me da miedo que se resienta.

Gracias.

Comment: Si, por supuesto, haciendo un sql directamente que actulice los datos que vos queres. investiga sobre Update.

Comment: Si, si algo de sql conozco y lo he utilizado para crear consultas sencillas en Access directamente, pero nunca había tenido que leer datos de una tabla/rango y cargarlos/actualizarlos en Access. 

Seguiré buscando.

Comment: En lugar de hacer el select, solo haces el update al registro que queres. No necesitas traer los datos y modificarlos. Access lo hace por vos.

Comment: Podrías probar a importarte todos los datos a una nueva tabla temporal, y luego ya haces un update en cadena de todos los registros, porque el campo ID relaciona ambas tablas. Luego vacías la temporal y punto.